# $translateProvider.useStaticFilesLoader with external source

Tags: angularjs, angular-translate

I was trying to use useStaticFilesLoader with external source.

```
$translateProvider.useStaticFilesLoader({
  prefix: 'http://localhost:3001/i18n/',
  suffix: '.json'
});
```

Source json is downloading correctly from location Ex- http://localhost:3001/i18n/sw.json. But language translation is not working.

Here is how I am using it.

```
<h2 class="ops" data-translate="ERROR_IMAGE_AREA_SELECT_MULTIPLE _SELECTION"></h2>
```